# Error con las redes en Linux

Tags: linux, redes

tengo un error con el nameserver de linux, cada vez que se apaga y prende mi computadora pierdo acceso a internet y cuando voy al archivo resolv.conf encuentro que no tengo ningun DNS y tengo que agregar uno, el que uso es el de google 8.8.8.8. Alguno sabe porque es esto y como arreglarlo

El archivo resolv.conf muestra lo siguiente

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
```

Comment: _Stack Overflow ES_ es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas de programación. Para dudas  de administración Linux tienes los sitios (askubuntu)[https://askubuntu.com/] para administración de Ubuntu, y [Unix y Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) para administración Linux y Unix en general. Ambos son parte de la _Stack Exchange_, al igual que _Stack Overflow ES_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El fichero está siendo configurado por la aplicación NetworkManager, debes revisar a través del sistema GUI que estés usando (KDE, Gnome, etc.) que lo estés configurando correctamente, en caso de que quieras configurarlos directamente en el archivo **/etc/network/interfaces** deberías revisar la configuración:

```
#==============
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp0s31f6
iface enp0s31f6 inet static
        address 192.168.100.4/24
        gateway 192.168.100.1
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 1.1.1.1
```

Ojo que al configurar el archivo /etc/network/interfaces ya no podrá ser gestionado por NetworkManager (GUI)